# How can we Invoke-SqlCmd execute query with "sa" user and empty password

Tags: powershell

I have prepared one power shell script. In this script, I executed SQL Query but this script generating error because of an empty password. You can see my code and error screenshot also as shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the actual content of the script?

Comment: Why would SQL Server allow you to connect as `sa` with a blank/no password? Sounds like it's working as designed :)

Comment: Looks like your script is declaring that `-Password` is a mandatory parameter, so you get the error because you have omitted that parameter. (This is just a guess, since you did not paste your script into your question.)

Comment: As -password is a required flag, just set a blank password in your script: `-password ""`.

Comment: Please, [do not upload image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/503046) about the error message.

Comment: @isaac I uploaded code image please check it

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I don't want to create extra users because one .net application already using "sa" with a blank password.

Comment: And the error please too

Comment: @issac I uploaded an error image also please check it.

Comment: I mean the error is pretty clear? your password argument is empty and it's spitting back an error.

Comment: Did the answer help fix this? @VikashSaharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is clearly showing that you need to have the password parameter filled and not left as empty. Populating the password field especially when trying to connect as `sa` should fix your issue here

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't want to create a new user and don't change the password of "sa" user because another application is also using this user